# Epoch time to Date time in palantir foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have a long column which gives epoch (which i can convert to date time [perfectly](https://www.epochconverter.com/))

[image]

I tried to do the same in palantir using below code as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64054689/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-date-in-foundry-contour).

```
CAST(CAST((utc_column) AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE)
```

But my contour analysis in palantir converts the date as 55346-06-08. I tried the column editor too and it gave the same result. Any idea as to how can i convert epoch time to correct date time in Palantir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNIX time you have is given in milliseconds, the `CAST AS TIMESTAMP` assumes it's in seconds.
All you have to do is divide by 1000 before converting.

Your expression should be: `CAST(CAST((utc_column/1000) AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE)`